# grpc in GAE Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, grpc, grpc-python

Is it possible to host a gRPC server in GAE Standard environment using Python? I have seen https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/tutorials which seems to me you have to use ESP to host a gRPC server in GCP (GAE Standard is not listed here). Is ESP the only way to implement a gRPC server? Can't I write my own gRPC implementation such as https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/ and host it in GAE Standard?

I apologize for the basic questions as gRPC is quite new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. gRPC support is not available for App Engine as mentioned in group conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/4CM0y5qNecY)
   .
2. Endpoints supports gRPC services for GKE, Compute Engine, and Cloud
   Run (Beta). The framework available for Cloud Endpoints control of API in App Engine for Python you can refer
   [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks)
    [Cloud Endpoints Frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks)

Comment: Thank you. So the recommended way to get a gRPC server running in gcp is to use ESP, is this understanding correct?

Comment: yes, Either the Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) or the Extensible Service Proxy V2 (ESPv2) to provide API management as mentioned in document.